# Copying the answer with all code at once

Tags: support, answers, export

Is there any way to copy the entire best answer, along with all the TeX codes at once (something like right click => select all => copy) for reference or further offline use?

Comment: You might be interested in some of the past discussions tagged ([meta-tag:export]). For example, [Save the answer in PDF?](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/15163) or [Save the answer in TEX?](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/15230)

Comment: And judging by the accepted answer, you are actually interested in this: [Quoting other posts without going to edit](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/20557).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The easiest way is to click the [edit] link under the answer. It will contain the source [Markdown](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/formatting) of the post (or HTML, but not many people use that). The [TeX commands](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020/228959) will be included.

[image]

---

Another way is via the Revisions page. If an answer has been edited, you can click the 'Edited by' link underneath the answer; otherwise, you'll have to construct the URL manually. It contains the answer's ID and looks like this:

https://math.stackexchange.com/posts/2255919/revisions

You can click the [source] link to see the source of the post. This works even if the [edit] link is disabled (e.g. because there is another suggested edit pending).

[image]

Comment: wonderful. works great!